# Arduino append request parameter

Tags: arduino

Hello everyone i have been struggling with a post request in arduino now for the some time. Am not very fluent in c++ but i have been having problems with appending a string to char* or converting a string to char*. Below is my code. Am using a library i downloaded from github.https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient.

```
 void connectToRemote(int id)
    {

      int err =0;

      EthernetClient c;
      HttpClient http(c);


    uint16_t port = 8080;
    String path = "/AutomaticAccessSystem/register?studentnumber="+(String)studentNumber+"&fingerId="+(String)id;
    const char* url = path.c_str();
    const char* method = "GET";
    const char* serverName = "169.254.6.174";

    //the method below takes in only char* as arguments
    err = http.startRequest(server, serverName, port, url, method, NULL);

    err = http.responseStatusCode();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(err);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Am able to successfully make the call if i dont append studentNumber and fingerid to the url with `char* url="/AutomaticAccessSystem/register"`. The studentNumber is of the type char[] and fingerid is int. Please help me figure out where the problem is. Am not good with c++. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
//String path = "/AutomaticAccessSystem/register?studentnumber="+(String)studentNumber+"&fingerId="+(String)id;
const char* url = "/AutomaticAccessSystem/register?studentnumber="+(String)studentNumber+"&fingerId="+(String)id;
```

you trying to put a variable in a constant, i don't know much C++, but i think that could be this